# Why would I use a Kendo model instead of only using a transport/datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, model

I am currently looking at Kendo UI and was wandering what is the "advantage" of defining a model in my schema. It seems to work quite well without. Is this for binding reasons (i.e. column discovery for Grid control for example) ? Does it allow particular validations ?

Thanks

Pat

Answer (score 2):

You can use the schema model to specify your data model. On a grid, you can for example set:

- Which data type the field has (if set to number, the column filter offers e.g. 'greater than, 'less than' instead of 'contains' etc. for string values).

  - If a grid field is editable or not (when grid is set to editable)
  - Several validation properties
  - ...

I usually receive the grid data from a web service in JSON, so everything is a string initially. By using the model I influence how these values are displayed and how they behave.

See also
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model
and http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model
for a full overview of possibilities.